# SQL Server: finding the bad data

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I select all rows except for ones that where I get an error calling `CONVERT` on one of the columns?

For example, I am doing this:

```
SELECT rowid 
FROM batchinfo 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, reporttime, 101) between '2010-07-01' and '2010-07-31';
```

And I am getting errors for some of the values.  I have two questions:

1. How can I skip the rows that have errors?
2. How can I get *only* the rows that have errors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the ISDATE() function to test the values.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ISDATE(MyColumn) != 1
```

Comment: MAN do I feel dumb.  I've been developing with SQL server for 10 years, and I never knew there was an IsDate() function. How is that possible? +1 to you and thank you. And thanks to the asker for asking this.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: @David Stratton: I'm beginning to hypothesize that familiarity with odd functionality like `ISDATE` is from having to make the best of bad data & horrible modeling.  Without the need, why would you know - right?

Comment: Hmm @Ponies, does that mean I know how to work with bad data (I accept), or that I'm a horrible modeler (may be true, but I'm not admitting it here)

Comment: @bobs: I was hoping I was clear that I meant working with the *aftermath* of bad modeling.  I think the familiarity is awesome, but I don't know if the experience is enough to actually improve modeling skills because the situations only show how **not** to do things -- not how they should be, sadly.

Comment: I second @David's response.  I use StackExchange all the time but never seemed to look for ways to find bad data yet run into it all the time.  FYI, ISNUMERIC() exists as well and what I was ultimately looking for.  Thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can utilize the IGNORE statement for this, I may be wrong though.